# Migrating a question to another Stack Exchange network site

Tags: discussion, support, migration, migrated-questions

I want to migrate [a question I wrote on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266700/whats-the-border-radius-of-the-new-chrome-tab-design-chrome-version-69) by mistake to the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com).

When I try to close the question as off-topic and associate it with another Stack Exchange site I get very limited options, only five other sites in the network:

[image: Associating to another site in the Stack Exchange network]

Am I looking for an option that doesn't exist? and if so why? Isn't it supposed to be legitimate to move questions freely between the sites?

Comment: If you wrote it "by mistake", just delete and repost it.

Comment: I would try a custom flag in this case, if it's your own question.